# Add element to the xml string in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following relatively simple scenario, but it’s working.

I need an append to my xml string, here's the scenario:

```
val xmlStr = "<return> <numberPin> 123456 </numberPin> </return>"
```

I need some way to add the element data and return the string below, I would like some solution with regular expression if possible

```
"<return> <numberPin> 123456 </numberPin> <date> 2019-09-04 00:00:00 </date> </return>"
```

Comment: Maybe you can share what you have tried to get this done? Was there any error messages?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with apache-spark? If so, you need to include some more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template xml at first that can be updated at runtime.

You can do something like below:

```
def updateXml (xmlStr:String, dateContent: String) = {
  xmlStr.replace("DATE_DATA", dateContent)
}

val xmlStr = "<return> <numberPin> 123456 </numberPin> DATE_DATA </return>"
val dateData = "<date> 2019-09-04 00:00:00 </date>"
updateXml(xmlStr, dateData)
```

Another alternative is to create an xml template in a file(if the xml content is like a big file). Read it in your code and insert required data at run-time as shown in the above example(where i stuffed DATE_DATA in template and replaced it at runtime using the method).